# Vue nested routing does not including dynamic parameters

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have two routes, say posts & pages, inside each user route, like 
`/user/foo/pages`, `user/foo/posts`, `/user/bar/pages`, `user/bar/posts`
where `foo` and `bar` are the dynamic content. However nested routing in vue does not including those `foo` and `bar`

router.js

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/user/:id',
      name: 'user',
      component: User,
      children: [
        {path: 'posts', name: 'posts', component: Posts},
        {path: 'pages', name: 'pages', component: Pages},
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

User.vue

```
<router-link to="posts">Posts</router-link>
<router-link to="pages">Pages</router-link>
```

The result vue is producing when i am already inside `foo` or `bar`, is

```
<a href="#/user/posts">Posts</a>
<a href="#/user/posts">Pages</a>
```

However the expected result should be (when i am inside `foo`)

```
<a href="#/user/foo/posts">Posts</a>
<a href="#/user/foo/pages">Pages</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use object with name and params in your router-link, like this

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'posts', params: {id: $route.params.id}}">Posts</router-link>
```

Answer (score 1):

i read vue-router souce code then see that they pop last item out of stack. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sygsG.png)

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/11e779ac94eb226e4f52677003ff8d80e5648885/dist/vue-router.common.js#L447

it works as you expected when you add trailing slash into parent path

path: '/user/:id' -> path: '/user/:id/'